# how to get real date (not system date) by c# or c++?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get real date (not system date) without any connection to internet?
I developed my application by C#.
DateTime.Now gets system date but I want to know real date because system date may be wrong.

Is it possible? How to do this?

Comment: Define "real date." If you can't trust the system date and you can't connect to the internet for any type of master-clock response... no.

Comment: You may think it is hard to get a real date without an Internet connection, but there are traditional methods that don't involve dating websites or Facebook. I recommend going outside, attending social events, and good hygiene.

Comment: Without an internet connection, you can prompt the user for the real date, then change the system date to what they entered.  You can then proceed to use the system date. :)  Another option is if they have a webcam.  You can scan the room's content and see if you can find a calendar with today's date.

Comment: @Michael: I know you beat me to it, but really, we independently came up with the same solution?? :P

Comment: Telepathically, perhaps?

Comment: @Nelson +1 for the webcam solution! Would make for a great hobby project, no?

Comment: @SystemDown: Yeah, the quality would have to be pretty good to be able to OCR it and calendars can have some strange fonts.  How would you know which *day* it is (unless it's a daily calendar)? And last but not least, who actually has their calendar on the right month?

Answer (score 8):

If the system date is wrong, then your application has to get the correct date from somewhere else. That means and outside resource. It can be over the web, it could be another server in your network, or you could enter it manually. There are no magical solutions.

Answer (score 3):

No. In the absence of any external communications, all you've got is the clock in the computer. If you're not going to trust that, you're stuffed.

Of course, if you're trying to prevent someone from blowing a timed trial licence of software, you could do things like recording the latest UTC time you've ever seen, and becoming suspicious if you see an *earlier* startup time than the previous startup... especially if you see that repeatedly. That's not the same as getting the real date, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this if you know how much your system date varies from the "real date."  If you have this delta in a TimeSpan object, you could then do create the "real date" by using `DateTime.Now.Add(delta)`.  If you don't have a network connection, you'll have to get the delta some other way, such as a user-entered value.  This will be tough though, as the frequency of the system clock on a machine can vary.

Answer (score 2):

Even without the internet, there *are* other "reliable" external time sources. However, the internet is the easiest and a number of time protocols/servers already exist. These are provided as thoughts, and not necessarily as viable solutions.

1. NIST atomic clock broadcasts (e.g. how those "atomic watches" work). I am not sure of any commodity hardware for a PC to read these signals. Go befriend an electronics engineer.
2. GPS. There is plenty of different GPS hardware available to connect to a PC (USB dongles, etc). Even, say, an iPhone. (Modern cell phones will get time synchronization from the network, even without GPS support.)
3. Your very own atomic clock! Drift should be ignorable ;-)

Happy ... stuff.

Comment: Hold your digital watch up to the webcam so your OCR software can read it?

Comment: @Jim: Are you sure you can trust the digital watch?  Does the watch know how to get the real date?

Comment: @Nelson: I don't about yours, but my digital watch is a suave sunavabitch. He can get a date whenever he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Without Internet you are going to need a GPS receiver or [Radio clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_clock) device.

You can call upon an NTP server if you can establish some form of Internet connection which should give accurate (atomic) time. C# doesn't have a built in NTP client that I know of but there is one available from:

http://mftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Info on NTP can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Comment: The question said, "without any connection to internet".