# Can we get ACTUAL date really?

Tags: c#, datetime

DateTime.Now returns current date. But if someone has changed system date, DataTime.Now will not actually return the real current data.

So the question is, Is there some some place in computer (may be processor or ...) which holds always the actual date? And if yes, how can we retrieve that data. Please assume that the application has not any access to internet and local network (it is completely disconnected).

Comment: Basically, no you can't. Not without special hardware (e.g. radio clock receiver which can read the time from a radio clock transmitter source)

Comment: In the past I retrieved the date/time from the BIOS. But this isn't completely fail safe.

Comment: You believe that CPU uses stars in the sky to define real current date?

Comment: Of course not. For *any* clock on the system there must be some way to manually change the time, so what it reports is what you told it to report.

Comment: The BIOS has a date - but, a: that is usually directly related to the OS date (give or take a minor offset), and b: it is just as susceptible to being changed...

Comment: You will most probably find your answer here : [how to get a real time clock in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875072/how-to-get-real-date-not-system-date-by-c-sharp-or-c) As far as I am concerned, the answer is no there is no other way.

Comment: No there isn't such a place. The universe has no notion of an absolute clock, that can be queried using electronics. The closest thing is the kind of clock you know, you probably have one on your bed side table, or around your wirst. There is one of those in the computer. That is the one that DataTime.Now reads.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, I wish it would have been. But plz read carefully... it states may be. So question is. Is there any other component

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get real date (not system date) by c# or c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875072/how-to-get-real-date-not-system-date-by-c-sharp-or-c)

Comment: I dont think @ShadowWizard, My scenerio is different. I have a machine which is totally disconnected

Comment: @Irfan how is it different? It is exactly the same scenario as far as how you have worded question goes.

Answer (score 7):

No.

There are precisely two ways to get the current time:

1. Check the time on the computer
2. Getting it from an external server (e.g. Internet, local network, some sort of radio broadcast...)

If you do not trust the time set on the computer itself, then your only option is the second one, and that necessarily requires a connection to a device where you *can* trust the system time.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no magic clock in computers that holds the correct time.

If you are interested in correct times you should look into [NTP (network time protokol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Comment: even NTP only tells you the time that the chosen NTP server wishes to convey... I wonder how far the OP's paranoia goes

Comment: You got to trust someone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is of course in the definition of the "real" date or time.

Maybe the OP has a clear idea about what is meant by that, but there *is* no such thing.

If I would have some place in my computer that would store the actual, correct, astronomically adjusted date, the moment I pick it up and i travel east or west, my "actual" date and time should have changed.

Now, how would the magic box in my computer know that?

So, no, there is no "actual" date/time.

There are two dates/times you can use:

1) the local one as reported by the user's system. As far as the user is concerned, this *is* the actual date/time.

2) a reference date/time, like UTC, or any current time in a predefined time zone. This has nothing to do with the clients reported date/time.

What you *can* do, of course, is trying to figure out the geographical location of the client, and calculate what the client's actual date/time *should* be as an offset from Zulu time.